# Parse only time with AM/PM in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to parse time in format 10:15 AM. But it is showing **FormatException: Invalid date format
10:15 AM**

My code

```
DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.parse('10:15 AM'));
```

Also tried

```
DateFormat('h:mm a').format(DateTime.parse('10:15 AM'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `10:15 AM` the `Datetime.parse` method don't accept this format.
Here are some example of accepted strings which can be found in the  [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html).

- "2012-02-27"
- "2012-02-27 13:27:00"
- "2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z"
- "2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z"
- "20120227 13:27:00"
- "20120227T132700"
- "20120227"
- "+20120227"
- "2012-02-27T14Z"
- "2012-02-27T14+00:00"
- "-123450101 00:00:00 Z": in the year -12345.
- "2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500": Same as "2002-02-27T19:00:00Z"

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = '10:30 PM';
DateTime startDatetime = newDateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat.jm().parse(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will take date month and year to parse it. Try creating a reference to current date

```
String timeString = 10:30 AM;
final now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
```

Next convert the string into hours and minutes. You can also use regex but to keep it simple let's split it.

```
int hour = int.parse(timeString.split(":")[0]);
int minute = timeString.split(":")[1].split(" PM")[0];
bool isPm = timeStrig.contains("AM")?true:false;
```

Now if you parse the string with date it should work.

```
DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day, isPm ? hour + 12 : hour, minute, second);
```